# Use strong induction to prove the following equation:

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Use strong induction to prove that $F_{n+1}-F_{n-1}< 2^n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Let $f(n) = F_{n+1} + F_{n-1}$

$f(n) \leq 2^n$

Base Case:

$f(1) \leq 2^1 = 2$

$f(2) \leq 2^2 = 4$

$f(3) \leq 2^3 = 8$

Induction Step:

Let $n \epsilon \mathbb{N} $ and assume that $f(n) \leq 2^n$ is true for all n =1 , 2, 3 .. k

I am stuck on this induction step. simply stating $f(k+1) \leq 2^{k+1}$ sounds incomplete. What should I do here?

Comment: What is $ F {}$?

Comment: @player3236 That is not given in the problem

Comment: Then how did you determine $f(1) \le 2$, $f(2) \le 4$ etc?

Comment: @player3236 Apologies, that is the fibonacci number

Comment: @maria Welcome to Math SE. Note $F_{n+1} - F_{n-1} = (F_{n} + F_{n-1}) - F_{n-1} = F_n$.

Comment: Please fix your question (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you know they're Fibonacci numbers, and you're allowed to assume the standard recursive definition, then it's trivially equivalent to proving $F_n < 2^n$.

Now you need to establish that $F_{n+1} < 2^{n+1}$.

Again using the standard recursive definition, $F_{n+1} = F_{n} + F_{n-1}$

Now apply the strong inductive hypothesis, and you get

$F_{n+1} = F_{n} + F_{n-1} < 2^n + 2^{n-1} = 2^n + \frac 12 \cdot 2^n = \frac 32 \cdot 2^n < 2\cdot 2^n = 2^{n+1}$

and you're pretty much finished.

---

EDIT: OK, I think I now understand the (inconsistently presented) question.

The result that needed to be proved was probably $F_{n+1} + F_{n-1} < 2^n$.

So the expression with the minus sign ($F_{n+1} - F_{n-1}$) was simply a typo. Nevertheless, as the question has not yet been fixed, I am leaving my previous working intact.

This statement ($F_{n+1} + F_{n-1} < 2^n$) is not difficult to prove either.

The strong inductive hypothesis is: $F_{n+1} + F_{n-1} < 2^n$ for all $n$ less than or equal to a certain value.

Now $F_{n+2} + F_{n} = (F_n + F_{n+1}) + (F_{n-1} + F{n-2})$

(rearrange)

$=(F_{n+1}+F_{n-1}) + (F_n + F_{n+2}) < 2^{n-1} + 2^n$

(applying the strong inductive hypothesis in the last step)

$=2^{n-1}(1 + 2) = 2^{n-1}(3) < 2^{n-1}(2^2) = 2^{n+1}$.

Therefore you have shown $F_{n+2} + F_{n} < 2^{n+1}$, and the proposition has been proven by strong induction.

The initial step is left to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using $f$, by definition of Fibonacci Numbers:

$$f(k+1) = F_{k+1} - F_{k-1} = (F_k+F_{k-1})-(F_{k-2}+F_{k-3}) = (F_k-F_{k-2})+(F_{k-1}-F_{k-3})\\=f(k)+f(k-2)$$

Now use your induction hypothesis.

Comment: Note that, based on the OP's definition of $f(n)$, your initial $f(k + 1)$ should be $f(k)$, and the $f(k)$ in the second line should be $f(k-1)$, or you'll need to rewrite the parts in between appropriately if you wish to use $f(k+1)$ instead initially.